# How to access SQL Server through internet?

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

I want to test a connection using SQL Server that can access through internet but I'm lost, I don't know where to start.

I know how to do it in MySQL but I want to know how to do it in SQL Server.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

One quick trick I know of, which works even on machines without SQL tools installed:

1. Create a new blank file somewhere and give it `.udl` for an extension. It should change to an icon with a table and a white page with 0s and 1s in the background.
2. Double-click on it to open the "Data Link Properties" dialog
3. On the Provider tab, choose "Microsoft OLEDB Provider for SQL Server"
4. On the Connection tab, fill in the remote server details and credentials
5. Click "Test Connection"

Answer (score 0):

Where to start?

Try looking for the [correct connection string here](https://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server/)

You then need to find an [example using the System.Data.SqlClient](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dw70f090%28v=vs.110%29.aspx#_SqlClient)

Answer (score 0):

By 'connect through the internet' do you mean connect from the internet to a SQL Server?

You need to open appropriate ports in the firewall and NAT them to your SQL Server.

Answer (score 0):

To get you started, I would install a copy of SQL Server Express onto your local workstation and create an SQL Server instance with SQL Server Authentication. Also install SQL Server Management Studio which is a visual console through which you can manage your database and logins etc. They are available for free here:

http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=29062

Go into SQL Server Management Studio, create a database and a login username and password with sysadmin rights. Connect using the following code. The principles are similar to connect to an SQL Server database over the internet only there are more security issues to take into account.

```
Dim sConnectionString As String = "Server= MYCOMPUTERNAME\SQLEXPRESS;Database=DATABASE_NAME;User ID=USER_ID;Password=PASSWORD;Trusted_Connection=False;

Try

    Dim mySqlConnection As New System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection()
    mySqlConnection.ConnectionString = sConnectionString
    mySqlConnection.Open()

    MessageBox.Show("You have connected successfully to the SQL Server database.")

Catch SqlEx As SqlException

    MessageBox.Show(SqlEx.Message & Constants.vbNewLine & Constants.vbNewLine & "You have NOT connected successfully to the SQL Server database.")

Catch ex As Exception

    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message & Constants.vbNewLine & Constants.vbNewLine & "You have NOT connected successfully to the SQL Server database.")

End Try
```